# Create x509 chain with c++ openssl lib

Tags: c++, openssl, x509

I have clientCA.key and clientCA.crt - intermediate private key and certificate.
Now, I generate endpoint private key and certificate request at command line:

`openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout clientEP.key -out clientEP.csr \
        -subj "/C=CA/ST=AAA/L=BBB/O=CCC/OU=DDD/CN=EEE/emailAddress=m@m"`

Then make endpoint certificate with signing by intermediate CA certificate and key:

`openssl x509 -req -CAkey clientCA.key -CA clientCA.crt -days 365  -in clientEP.csr -out clientEP.crt -set_serial 25 -extfile clientEP.cnf`

It's easy to generate RSA key and request:
 `RSA_generate_key_ex(keys, 2048,e, NULL);`
 `X509_REQ_new();`

but how can I get request signed by clientCA.key and clientCA.crt and take clientEP.crt with C++ Openssl library? Maybe it's possible to generate Endpoint certificate from this files without request?

Answer (score 0):

Openssl provides various functions and you can use them.
It's better to search more or visit an openssl org.
And read the description of each function carefully.

You can do like you did on linux(maybe),

1. Create a PrivateKey for an end-entity certificate.

```cpp
     EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new(void);
```

See: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_new.html

2. Create a RSA and set it to the PrivateKey

```cpp
    RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(1024, 3, 0, 0);
    EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(pkey, RSA *key);
```

See also https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA.html

3. Create a X509

```cpp
    X509 *cert = X509_new(void);
```

4. Set the pubkey(correstponded key to a privatekey made eariler)

```cpp
    X509_set_pubkey(cert, pkey);
```

5. Do a sign to clientEP using a privatekey of cliendCA.

```cpp
    X509_sign(cert, pkey, 0); // third param is a hashing option.
```

6. Set the specific profile of a cert.(I may miss some specific steps but you can do it)

You may get the information when you google it more.
In addition, openssl provides a write api such as BIO_write or PEM_write_X509 and so on.

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: thanks! Yes, I did it. Without certificate request. Also I set for EndPoint certificate issuer, subject and x509v3 extensions required values (from CA cert), so my EP cert looks like command line generated cert. But it doesn't work.  I think it because I didn't use this: `-CAkey clientCA.key`

Comment: And I read clientCA key with `privCA=PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(in, NULL, NULL, NULL)` , but if it encrypted by DES(or other), can I use it for `X509_sign(x509, privCA, EVP_sha256());`?

Comment: @lap108 , It's better to separate that.  `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` is converting a Base64 encoded string to `EVP_PKEY *`. So, you cannot use `X509_sign() api` because  `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` is not working for des encoded format. You need to use an api handling des format(actually decrypt it first). Take a look into `DES_ncbc_encrypt() `. [link](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/DES_ncbc_encrypt.html).  Please note that you need to call different apis according to its format.  Sometimes decryption or parsing is required.

Comment: Sorry, I have "nodes" clientCA.key, it begins with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey()` has correct result. I use: 1) generate key `RSA_generate_key_ex(k,2048,e,NULL),EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey,k)` ; 2) fill subject and issuer with `X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt()`. Also time, serial, version, extensions ( is this enough implementation of `-CA clientCA.crt` ? ) ; 3) set public key and sign  `X509_set_pubkey(x, pkey), X509_sign(x, clientCA,EVP_sha256())`. But it doesn't work with server(

Comment: If a certificate chain is creates properly, it should work on local and server as well. Please check id you have created proper certificate chain including a root cert. and then before doing it on a server(tls handshake), please do ut in your local without server. Do it on a linux with a command `openssl verify` or refer it[x509 verify cert](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/X509_verify_cert.html)